# Add a word before each extracted String

Tags: regex

I am capturing the session id from the string. I want to add word(prefix) before the extracted session id.

**Sample input:** `key=this is sample input; MySessionId=hhjsfd436763jhjhfdjs87787.hghht77f54; key7=jhu8787; type=raw; oldkey=jkjf8787;`

I have formed the below regex to capture the MySessionId.

```
MySessionId=([^.]*)
```

I want to add a word before the extracted string like below.

**Expected output:**

```
ABCD-1234-hhjsfd436763jhjhfdjs87787
```

Any way to achieve this through Regular expression?

Comment: Depends on your programming language. You could just prepend the word to the extracted string.

Comment: Will it possible through Regex ?

Comment: You can use the regex to get the value of capture group 1, and then concatenate `ABCD-1234-` with the group 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what language you're using, you'll need to find a function that replaces text in a string (usually it's called replace). It looks like you're dealing with cookies so I'll show you an example in javascript:

```js
//$1 refers to the first group captured by the regex
//i think other languages use $1 too but you should probably check
string = string.replace(/MySessionId([^.]*)/, "ABCD-1234-$1")
```